# filter with mapPropsStream doesn't work

Tags: rxjs, filtering, recompose

i'm trying to create a filter with `mapPropsStream` but it does not work. This is my code:

```
const BaseComponent = ({ onSearch, data }) => (
    <div>
        <input onChange={({ target }) => onSearch(target.value)} />
        <br/>
        <ul>
            {data.map((item) => /* render list */)}
        </ul>
    </div>
);

const DataList = mapPropsStream((props$) => {
    const { handler: onSearch, stream: onSearch$ } = createEventHandler();
    const filteredData$ = Observable.merge(
        onSearch$.switchMap((query) => 
            props$.pluck('data').filter((item) => 
                item.title.includes(query) || 
                item.body.includes(query) ||
                item.event.includes(query)
            )
        ),
        props$.pluck('data') // props$.map(({ data }) => data)
    ).startWith([]);

    return props$.combineLatest(
        filteredData$,
        (props, data) => ({
            ...props,
            data,
            onSearch
        })
    );
})(BaseComponent)

export default DataList;
```

i don't know if this is a correct way to filter data, if not, which is the correct way keeping in mind that my data is stored in redux?, if yes, what's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: When you say it "does not work" please provide information about what errors you see.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, i already solved my problem.